# my program window is not responding .why idk?

Tags: python, tkinter, error-handling

```
    
    import psutil
    import time
    from tkinter import *
    def eventc(event):
        while True :
            print(psutil.cpu_stats())
            time.sleep(2)
    
    def closewin(event):
        exit(0)
    
    def myevent(event):
        print('okayy')
    window=Tk()
    #button for stats
    btn=Button(window, text="click me for cpu stats", fg='blue')
    btn.place(x=80, y=100)
    btn.bind('<Button>',eventc)
    #btn for closing the window
    winclose=Button(window, text="close window", fg='blue')
    winclose.place(x=95, y=0)
    winclose.bind('<Button>',closewin)
    #for window
    window.title('my \'so called first app\'')
    window.geometry("300x200+10+10")
    window.mainloop()
```

When I click get cpu stats is gives me stats but the window will not respond after that.
and after forcefully ending the window it give me this exit code:Process finished with exit code -805306369 (0xCFFFFFFF)
can you help me why

Comment: The while loop inside `eventc()` will block tkinter `mainloop` from handling pending events and updates.  Use `.after()` instead of while loop.  There are several questions on SO on this issues.

Comment: can you give me an example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The while loop inside `eventc()` will block tkinter `mainloop` from handling pending events and updates.  Suggest to use `.after()` to replace the while loop:

```py
def eventc(event=None):
    print(psutil.cpu_stats())
    window.after(2000, eventc) # execute eventc() 2000ms later
```

Comment: thank you so much ... have a great life... i am so happy RN ... :)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))